# microsoft-graph java sdk: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.util.List com.azure.core.http.HttpHeader.getValuesList()'

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I'm trying out the microsoft-graph-sdk for Java

```
<dependency> 
   <groupId>com.microsoft.graph</groupId>
      <artifactId>microsoft-graph</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

And I'm just following the examples like:

```
         ClientSecretCredential clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredentialBuilder()
         .clientId(clientId)
         .clientSecret(jwt.getRawToken())
         .tenantId(tenant)
         .build();

         TokenCredentialAuthProvider tokenCredentialAuthProvider = new TokenCredentialAuthProvider(scopes,
            clientSecretCredential);

         GraphServiceClient graphClient = GraphServiceClient
          .builder()
          .authenticationProvider(tokenCredentialAuthProvider)
          .buildClient();

          User me = graphClient.me().buildRequest().get();
```

When I run this code I get:

```
was thrown by a user handler's exceptionCaught() method while handling the following exception:: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.util.List com.azure.core.http.HttpHeader.getValuesList()'
    at com.azure.core.http.netty.NettyAsyncHttpClient.lambda$bodySendDelegate$2(NettyAsyncHttpClient.java:115) ...
```

I'm running this on a Quarkus application.

What I'm missing here?

Thanks

Comment: Please make sure that you're using the latest Microsoft Graph SDK for Java [which is v3.1.0](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-java/) and see still if you can repro the issue or not.

Comment: Thank you for your anwser, I updated the version and the error is the same

Comment: hmm, ok. then i would suggest you to report the issue at the above github repro itself, so that they can fix it

Comment: I'm gettingt he same error when im trying to create a keyvault secret client